# AJAX/PHP login - error messages not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a login system where the user can enter in their credentials and it will redirect them to either a "client" view or an "admin" view of the website. This is working properly.

My issues is when the user types in incorrect credential information my error messages are being displayed, i.e. Invalid username and password.

Here is my login form:

```
<form name="ajaxform" id="ajaxform" action="auth/ajax-auth.php" method="POST" >
    <h4>Client Login</h4>
        <div id="error"></div>
            <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
            <input id="username" class="form-control" name='username' placeholder="Username">
            <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name='password' placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" id="loginbtn">Login</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

Now if the user enters in bad credentials my error message should be displayed within `<div id="error"></div>`.

Here is what `ajax-auth.php` looks like:

```
session_start();

error_reporting(E_ALL);                //THIS IS AMAZING0
ini_set('display_errors', 1);          // <----

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

include '../connection.php';
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == true)
    {
        $_SESSION["username"] = $username;

        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        if ($row["permission"] == 2)
        {
            $_SESSION["permission"] = 2;
            // Redirect to the admin login page.
            echo 'admin';
        }
        else if ($row["permission"] == 1)
        {
            $_SESSION["permission"] = 1;
            $_SESSION["userId"] = $row["user_id"];
            $_SESSION["account"] = $row["account_id"];
            echo 'client';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "User not found!";
        header("Location: ../index.html");
    }
```

And finally here is my AJAX function that handles my redirecting.

```
$("#ajaxform").submit(function(e)
                          {
        e.preventDefault();
        var username=$("#username").val();
        var password=$("#password").val();
        var dataString = 'username='+username+'&password='+password;
        if($.trim(username).length>0 && $.trim(password).length>0) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "auth/ajax-auth.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function(){ $("#loginbtn").val('Connecting...');},
                success: function(data){
                    if(data) {
                        //alert(data + " Logged in!");

                       if(data == "admin"){
                           window.location.href = "/TTW-Website-Final/admin/admin.php";
                       }
                       else if(data == "client"){

                        //uncomment when index.php page is ready
                        //window.location.href = "index.php";

                        window.location.href = "index.html";

                       }

                    } else {
                        $("#error").html("<span style='color:#cc0000'>Error:</span> Invalid username and password. ");
                        $("#loginbtn").val('Submit')
                    }
                }

            });            
        }
```

When I enter in bad credentials into my form and hit login nothing happens at all and I can't seem to figure out why. It should be displaying my error message that is in my Ajax function.

```
$("#error").html("<span style='color:#cc0000'>Error:</span> Invalid username and password. ");
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I know I am close to getting this to work how I need it to and it's probably something really silly I am overlooking, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: add `or die(mysqli_error($dbc));` at the end of every mysqli_query;

Comment: You should not do a `header()` redirect in a script that you call through ajax. And sql injection and plain-text passwords. That's bad.

Comment: @Dimi yes, that will be added as I have it everywhere else.

Comment: @jeroen why shouldn't I do this, and what would you recommend instead of `header()`? I took out password hashing/salt to reduce the size of code in my question.

Comment: You should always `echo` something out and check its value in the `success` function. Then you can take action based on that value. Just like you do now, but with a third option, like `data == 'unauthorized'`.

Comment: @jeroen So should I `echo` back something like "not found" and then in my `success` function have an `else if(data == "not found"){//display error..}`? Would that work in regards to displaying my error message for bad credentials?

Comment: @jeroen haha your edit answered my question before I even got to ask it, I will try this.

Comment: @jeroen yeah that fixed it thanks! Should I answer my own question or would you like to answer? or remove this one?

Comment: You can answer it if you like, could be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of jeroen I understand what I was doing wrong.

I should have echoed out a value if the results from my query returned false and then have a third option in my AJAX function that deals with the value returned to my success function.

Here is what I changed in regards to my PHP:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == true)
    {
        $_SESSION["username"] = $username;

        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        if ($row["permission"] == 2)
        {
          $_SESSION["permission"] = 2;
          // Redirect to the admin login page.
          echo 'admin';
        }
        else if ($row["permission"] == 1)
        {
           $_SESSION["permission"] = 1;
           $_SESSION["userId"] = $row["user_id"];
           $_SESSION["account"] = $row["account_id"];
           echo 'client';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "unauthorized";
    }
```

and within my AJAX function I added a third option to handle what happens with this returned value.

```
if(data) {
   if(data == "admin"){
        window.location.href = "/TTW-Website-Final/admin/admin.php";
    }
    else if(data == "client"){
        window.location.href = "index.html";
    }
    else if(data == "unauthorized"){
       $("#error").html("<span style='color:#cc0000'>Error:</span> Invalid username and password. ");
       $("#loginbtn").val('Submit')
    }
}
```

Doing this resolved my issue and my error messages are being displayed if I add in incorrect credentials.